# C++ "map" in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I was wondering if there is a C++ "map"-like thing in Python. For example if I have 10^9 items and each one needs to hold one value: True or False (only the "True"-values are meaningful, but in order to check fast and not in O(n^2)), my code is very inefficient:

```
for k in range(0, numberOfItems):
myList.append([False])
```

I can check the value is True or False, but with larger numbers, like 10^9, I get a runtime error because of the list size. It just can't hold that many items. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Python's dictionaries are like C++ maps.

Comment: Use a dictionary?

Comment: Why are you appending `[False]` instead of just `False`?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: the built-in `dict` object is a hashmap.

Comment: Although if you can't make a list of 10^9 items, you probably wouldn't be able to create a dict, either.

Comment: If your problem is slow lookup, use a dictionary: `dct = {}; ... dct[k] = True`, which has O(1). If your problem is memory usage, dictionaries won't help, but neither would C++'s map, which is not memory-efficient.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, since this map simply holds a value of true or false, then you could just check membership in a `set` anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I think that solved the problem.

Comment: yeah, the best solution is probably a `set` that only contains the `True` indexes.

Comment: @user4815162342 indeed. However, it isn't really look-up that is slow on a list, i.e. `bool_list[i]` is just as fast (probably *faster*) than `bool_map[i]`. It's membership testing that is constant time with a map.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure that exist you can use dictionary ! 
See docs for more informations over how it works : [link to python documentation over dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: You should give an example (not shown at first posting this type of question) and not just a referal. Please improve your answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. To make sure that answers are always helpful and up to date, link-only answers are discouraged. You can improve your answer buy giving some context around the documentation by showing how to use a dictionary yourself, for example. You can learn more about how to give an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer